# DynamoDB [Java] - query for nested JSON document attribute value

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

as title of the questions says; is it possible in DynamoDB to query for a particular attribute value within a nested JSON document? I've been looking for the answer on official docs, SO, forums, etc., however I'm still unable to provide a valid query.

Example of the entity objects in Java:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Car")
public class Car {
    @DynamoDBHashKey
    String id;

    String color;

    String type;

    Engine engine;
}

@DynamoDBDocument
public class Engine {
    String manufacturer;
    int hp;
    String model;
}
```

Records in database:

```
{
    "id" : "43-asdasda4214ads13-13",
    "color" : "blue",
    "type" : "sedan",
    "engine" : {
        "manufacturer" : "ford",
        "hp" : 450,
        "model" : "av15"
    }
}
{
    "id" : "24ads123-adad123-das1",
    "color" : "red",
    "type" : "cabrio",
    "engine" : {
        "manufacturer" : "peugeot",
        "hp" : 130,
        "model" : "ig31-2"
    }
}
```

Can I query, let's say all cars which have `engine` provided by `ford`? If so, how could I do that? I've already tried `keyConditionExpression` in following format `engine.manufacturer = ford`, but no success. What I'd like to avoid is using `FilterExpression`.

Thanks in advance!